# How to enable sleep/standby on Windows Server 2012 Hyper V

Tags: hyper-v, electrical-power, windows-server-2012

I know it's possible because sleep works in HyperV under Windows 8.

edit: I know this is probably not "supported".

Comment: `know` is a very strong word.

Comment: I'm curious what the use case is for sleeping a hyper-v server.

Comment: I'm running Server 2012 (without Hyper-V installed though), and the only place I see a sleep option is on the shutdown menu accessible via `Alt+F4` from the desktop. Via the regular shutdown menu (in the charms bar or whatever it's called), I only have Shutdown and Restart.

Comment: I'm interested in the downvotes. Is saving energy not a key reason for virtualisation? Or is asking the 'impossible' poorly regarded?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: 1. Lack of evidence of research (even as little as "I found a link to where it's "not supported" 2. Making unsupported assumptions about two different products being the same. 3. Something well outside "normal" for a professional environment; it's usually a good idea to add a sentence about why you're creating an unsupported, odd-ball configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the server version of Windows, you can't. [Once the Hyper-V role loads, hibernate and sleep are disabled](http://blogs.technet.com/b/doxley/archive/2008/02/13/insomnia-causing-hyper-v.aspx).

You can sleep on Windows 8 Hyper-V because it is ["Client Hyper-V"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx) in which sleep states remain enabled. (Windows IT Pro has a [list of differences between Server and Client Hyper-V](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/virtualization2/features-server-hyperv-arent-client-hyperv-143070), and this appears among them.)

If you really need Hyper-V installed but still want to enable sleep/hibernate selectively, a [workaround](http://blogs.technet.com/b/doxley/archive/2008/09/05/getting-some-sleep.aspx) is available which will disable the Hyper-V role from loading. When it's not loaded, you can put the machine to sleep/hibernate it. You need to reboot after applying these registry keys.

> Gain hibernation/sleep - lose Hyper-V:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hvboot]
> "Start"=dword:00000003
> ```
>
> Lose hibernation/sleep - gain Hyper-V:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hvboot]
> "Start"=dword:00000000
> ```

Comment: Thanks but this is the best answer for Windows Server 2008 R2 and earlier, not Windows Server 2012. HyperV now supports sleep I just need to figure out how to enable it on Server.

Comment: What makes you think Microsoft changed their mind on this?

Comment: I don't think it's a case of "changed their mind" more as a "implemented the feature". Docs are here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx

Comment: You have to use Windows 8 for that.

Comment: It's the same binaries, just different configuration.

Comment: Well, you have your answer. I'm sorry you don't like it, but that doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: @Fowl, the binaries for Hyper-V in Win8 and Server2012 are not the same. I couldn't enumerate every difference, but there definitely are differences.

Comment: @ChrisS [Sleep is supported for Windows server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831410.aspx#BKMK_Sleep1)

Comment: @oleksii Maybe you mean to direct that toward someone else? I never said anything about sleep support.

Comment: @ChrisS sorry, that's right :) I asked a new question as the solution described in this answer doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: @oleksii The documentation you linked to is still wrong. Expect MS to correct it soon.

Comment: @MichaelHampton cheers, I will wait until Win Server 2012 R2 RTM version is available and perform an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of features in Hyper-V that don't work when you sleep the host machine.  Most of them, like SR-IOV networking, revolve around the use of an I/O MMU.  Client (Windows 8) Hyper-V doesn't support an I/O MMU, so it can sleep.