# How to enable "Sleep" for Windows 2012 server

Tags: windows-server-2012

I recently installed Windows Server 2012. This will serve as the dev-instance for our engineers and will be accessed in multiple time zones. I therefore plan to run this 24x7 but want to conserve energy by going to sleep mode when not in use & enable Wake-On-Magic-Packet.

Based on the previous [***post***](https://serverfault.com/questions/430628/how-to-enable-sleep-standby-on-windows-server-2012-hyper-v) it appears that there is no option to sleep Win Server 2012 with Hyper-V. Since I don't care much about virtualization now, I uninstalled Hyper-V.

In addition to this, I have done the following

1) Ran powercfg -a. Don't find sleep.

2) Added [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hvboot]
"Start"=dword:00000003 to try gaining sleep - no luck!

3) Only see Shutdown and Restart in power options.

Please help me sleep and save the planet :-)

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: A server does not sleep. A workstation can sleep, but a sever must still be available for requests at any time. Otherwise it isn't a server.

Comment: If you want to save the planet then plant trees as compensation. And pay for "green" energy.

Comment: There is a way to sleep Windows Server 8. http://arjunachith.blogspot.com/2010/06/enable-hibernate-and-sleep-with-hyper-v_05.html. Is there something similar for 2012?

Comment: @Ramesh No. There isn't.

Comment: @mailq : a server can serve request at specific times, not all the times.
You don't answer the question.

Comment: Check power options in the following link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn690048(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: A server could also take coffee breaks. This would be easy to accomplish on firewall level.

Answer (score 1):

I tried powercfg/hibernate ON in windows server 2012 Command Prompt with Admin rights. And now I see the hibernate option in "power options" in control panel.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be achieved is by going into the power settings, and changing the power plan to put the computer to sleep after, say, 2 minutes. It will then sleep as desired.