# How to enable hibernation on Windows Server 2012 with Hyper-V role?

Tags: windows-server-2012, electrical-power, hibernate

I have Windows Server 2012 installed on a laptop. I need a *server* because I develop software that I need to test specifically on a server edition. Documentation for [Windows Server 2012 says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831410.aspx#BKMK_Sleep1)

> Sleep and hibernate are no longer disabled when the Hyper-V role is
>   installed.
>
> **What value does this change add?**
>
> Computers running Hyper-V
>   can be put into sleep or hibernate mode. This is particularly useful
>   to users who are running Hyper-V on laptops computers.

#### Question

How to enable hibernation on Windows Server 2012 with Hyper-V role?

#### Things I tried

- [Modify registry for **hvboot**](https://serverfault.com/a/430633/82856). I did not have **hvboot** folder in the registry, so I added it manually, rebooted

  ```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hvboot]
  "Start"=dword:00000003
  ```

  No effect.
- Pressed *Alt+F4* on desktop, no Sleep or Hibernate available

[image: shut down options]

- Stop Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service in *service.msc* (which points to C:\Windows\system32\vmms.exe), all other Hyper-V services were stopped by default.
- Executed as Administrator

  ```
  powercfg.exe /hibernate on
  ```

  This is the output

  ```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
  (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  C:\Windows\system32>powercfg.exe /hibernate on
  Hibernation failed with the following error: The request is not supported.

  The following items are preventing hibernation on this system.
          An internal system component has disabled hibernation.
                  Hypervisor

  C:\Windows\system32>powercfg.exe /a
  The following sleep states are not available on this system:
      Standby (S1)
          The system firmware does not support this standby state.
          An internal system component has disabled this standby state.
                  Hypervisor

      Standby (S2)
          The system firmware does not support this standby state.
          An internal system component has disabled this standby state.
                  Hypervisor

      Standby (S3)
          An internal system component has disabled this standby state.
                  Hypervisor

      Hibernate
          An internal system component has disabled hibernation.
                  Hypervisor

      Standby (Connected)
          The hypervisor does not support this standby state.
          The system firmware does not support this standby state.

      Hybrid Sleep
          Standby (S3) is not available.
          Hibernation is not available.
          The hypervisor does not support this standby state.

      Fast Startup
          Hibernation is not available.


  C:\Windows\system32>
  ```

Comment: +1 for a well written question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked to is in error. This is a feature expected to be a part of 2012R2. That section of the article should be labeled as requiring R2.

Comment: I wonder what will happen to the guests when the host goes into hibernation...

Comment: @RyanRies from the article: "When entering sleep or hibernate Hyper-V will save running virtual machines. When coming out of sleep or hibernate Hyper-V will attempt to restart the virtual machines that were running before entering sleep or hibernate."

Comment: This feature exists in Client Hyper-V for Windows 8, but not in Server 2012. No idea what it's doing in that Technet article, as it's clearly erroneous.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The article was updated to include details for R2. When they made the change, they should have noted the R2 requirement for that feature.

Comment: The behavior seems to persist in 2012r2.  I'm running it and get the same powercfg output as the OP.